# Tool to correct invalid CSV files

Tags: ruby, validation, csv, tidy, htmltidy

Is there any command-line tool or ruby library to clean/correct invalid .csv files, something like tidy for html?

Example of error: unescaped non-successive double quotes.

Related to: [Regular expression to find and replace unescaped Non-successive double quotes in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180842/regular-expression-to-find-and-replace-unescaped-non-successive-double-quotes-in).

Answer (score 1):

You have a look at this program http://www.flat-file.net/.  Its build using .net however it does have a command line option.

Comment: Hmm.. why is Google showing the site as containing malware?

Comment: Yes l did get that a couple of weeks back not now though, a false positive?